# How to search exact string using python file handling

Tags: python

I have a file that contains

```
"1111 1111 1111 // google 
1111 1111 1111 // google talk browser 
1111 1111 1111 // google talks 
1111 1111 1111 // google talk"
```

I want to print only "// google talk" related line (only 4th line)

tried like this this not working...

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for index, line in enumerate(handle, 1):
        if line.strip() == 'talk':
            print 'Match found on line', index
```

Comment: What do you mean by "search exactly without extra string"? What is your desired output in this example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for index, line in enumerate(handle, 1):
        if line.rstrip().endswith("// google talk") # or .endswith("talk")
            print 'Match found on line', index
```

Comment: yes I edited pls help the above query